Google cloud build failing while running apply deploy steps
I am using Google cloud build for the first time to deploy to GKE. The first time i ran the triggers, It ran well, when i tried running it again, Its failing on the apply steps.
Below is the error code
{
  "textPayload": "Step #4 - \"Apply deploy\": for: \"STDIN\": error when patching \"STDIN\": Operation cannot be fulfilled on deployments.apps \"api\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again",
  "insertId": "35a9c46d-4b4e-4a87-aa0f-2ffca7eca30a-2055",
  "resource": {
    "type": "build",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "pay-441518",
      "build_id": "35a9c46d-4b4e-4a87-aa0f-2ffca7eca30a",
      "build_trigger_id": "71d1fa6a-ad0d-4bfc-a4cf-1ab73b118e07"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-11-26T23:58:40.632669490Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "labels": {
    "build_tags": "gcp-cloud-build-deploy,api,trigger-71d1fa6a-ad0d-4bfc-a4cf-1ab73b118e07",
    "build_step": "Step #4 - \"Apply deploy\""
  },
  "logName": "projects/pay-441518/logs/cloudbuild",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-11-26T23:58:40.990197165Z"
},
{
  "textPayload": "Step #4 - \"Apply deploy\": Error: failed to apply deployment: failed to apply Deployment configuration file with name \"api\" to cluster: failed to apply config from string: command to apply kubernetes config from string to cluster failed: exit status 1",
  "insertId": "35a9c46d-4b4e-4a87-aa0f-2ffca7eca30a-2056",
  "resource": {
    "type": "build",
    "labels": {
      "build_id": "35a9c46d-4b4e-4a87-aa0f-2ffca7eca30a",
      "project_id": "pay-441518",
      "build_trigger_id": "71d1fa6a-ad0d-4bfc-a4cf-1ab73b118e07"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-11-26T23:58:40.634748402Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "labels": {
    "build_tags": "gcp-cloud-build-deploy,api,trigger-71d1fa6a-ad0d-4bfc-a4cf-1ab73b118e07",
    "build_step": "Step #4 - \"Apply deploy\""
  },
}

This is the cloudbuild.yaml file
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '-t'
      - '$_IMAGE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - .
      - '-f'
      - $_DOCKERFILE_NAME
    dir: $_DOCKERFILE_DIR
    id: Build
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - '$_IMAGE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
    id: Push
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy
    args:
      - prepare
      - '--filename=$_K8S_YAML_PATH'
      - '--image=$_IMAGE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - '--app=$_K8S_APP_NAME'
      - '--version=$COMMIT_SHA'
      - '--namespace=$_K8S_NAMESPACE'
      - '--label=$_K8S_LABELS'
      - '--annotation=$_K8S_ANNOTATIONS,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID'
      - '--create-application-cr'
      - >-
        --links="Build
        details=https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/$BUILD_ID?project=$PROJECT_ID"
      - '--output=output'
    id: Prepare deploy
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |-
        if [ "$_OUTPUT_BUCKET_PATH" != "" ]
        then
          gsutil cp -r output/suggested gs://$_OUTPUT_BUCKET_PATH/config/$_K8S_APP_NAME/$BUILD_ID/suggested
          gsutil cp -r output/expanded gs://$_OUTPUT_BUCKET_PATH/config/$_K8S_APP_NAME/$BUILD_ID/expanded
        fi
    id: Save configs
    entrypoint: sh
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy
    args:
      - apply
      - '--filename=output/expanded'
      - '--cluster=$_GKE_CLUSTER'
      - '--location=$_GKE_LOCATION'
      - '--namespace=$_K8S_NAMESPACE'
    id: Apply deploy
images:
  - '$_IMAGE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
substitutions:
  _GKE_CLUSTER: ropay-gks-cluster-staging
  _K8S_LABELS: ''
  _IMAGE_NAME: gcr.io/ropay-441518/github.com/ropayorg/ropay-api-backend
  _K8S_APP_NAME: api-hub
  _K8S_NAMESPACE: staging
  _OUTPUT_BUCKET_PATH: ropay-441518_cloudbuild/deploy
  _K8S_YAML_PATH: kubernetes/
  _K8S_ANNOTATIONS: gcb-trigger-id=71d1fa6a-ad0d-4bfc-a4cf-1ab73b118e07
  _DOCKERFILE_DIR: ropay-laravel-backend
  _GKE_LOCATION: europe-west2
  _DOCKERFILE_NAME: Dockerfile
tags:
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy
  - $_K8S_APP_NAME

This works on the first build but not on the second build. It fails for some reason and i don't know why. Any advice would be appreciated

Please edit the question by sharing detailed steps that anyone can use to replicate the behavior? Also share logs from the console by editing your question? Also have a look at this Link.
